# Input type text not dissapears in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm developing a website, and on the login screen, there are 2 `<input type=text>` fields to put email and password, the thing is, in IE8 the text fields appear for like 2 seconds and then disappear, I can still type in the space, but you just can't see the fields

In Chrome, Firefox, IE9 its all working nice, in IE9 using compatibility mode IE8 it does work, only in a computer with IE8 installed this happens, you can check it on the link

http://kastulo.herobo.com

```
<body>
<!--[if lte IE 7]><script src="js/ie6/warning.js"></script>      <script>window.onload=function(){e("js/ie6/")}</script><![endif]-->

<div id="login_form">

<?php
    //Forma de ENTRADA DE USUARIOS
    echo form_open('login/validate_form');?>
        <input type="email", name="email" id="email_entrada" value="<?php set_value('email');?>">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="pass_entrada">
        <input type="image" width="150" height="50" src="<?php echo base_url();?>css/images/boton_entrar.png" name="submit" id="btn_entrar" class="center">
        <?php
        echo validation_errors('<p class="error center" id="login_errors">');
    echo form_close(); //FIN de forma de ENTRADA DE USUARIOS

?>
</div>

</body>
```

EDIT:it actually is type="password" and type="email"

and my css for the fields is:

```
#email_entrada{
position: relative;
top:195px;
}

#pass_entrada{
position: relative;
top:246px;
}

#login_form input[type="password"], input[type="email"]{
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 16px;
display: block;
padding:5px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 230px;
color: white;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1.5px -2.5px #FFFFFF;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1.5px -2.5px #FFFFFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1.5px -2.5px #FFFFFF;
background-color: #3A3A3A;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
behavior: url('ie-css3.htc');
}
```

any ideas why this might be happening?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and CSS in your post.

Comment: You have a script tag outside of your html block. Try moving that inside the body tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having seems indicative of a problem with the `ie-css3.htc` behaviour you are loading (in CSS), which only affects Internet Explorer 8 and below. Try reading up on the [known problems with IE-CSS3](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/).

Also consider removing IE-CSS3 entirely if your site can do with a lesser look on older versions of Internet Explorer. In my opinion using 'hacks' like these is a bad idea if you are unable to resolve the quirks that they can cause.

Comment: ok, let me check that info you posted on IE CSS3 and try removing it, see if that works